# aspstate nesting transaction error ms sql error

Tags: asp.net, sql, state

I have the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'aspstate.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'.
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 238, current count = 239. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I found the cause of the exception:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/greglow/archive/2007/02/04/improving-asp-net-session-state-database-performance-by-reducing-blocking.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have unclosed begin statments by the  looks of it. Needs to be closed with a commit statment or End statement. Seems to be occusring on the other side of a webservice call that you're making

Comment: These mean if I have too or more web allication with the same aspstate then i can get these error?

Comment: @saj: Read the error: there is a missing table that causes the trancount mismatch. @Haroldis: this answer is useless. Why did you accept it?

Comment: for these:No, this is purely a SQL script error. – saj 19 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** errors

1. Invalid object name 'aspstate.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'.
2. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of...

The mismatch of BEGIN/COMMIT is caused by a run-time compile failure because the table aspstate.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions is missing.

So an extra BEGIN was executed but it never got to the COMMIT.

If @@TRANCOUNT is 238, it could be that someone dropped the table after 238 executions